# Django update fields base on the current fields values

Tags: python, django, django-models

Given the schema:

```
stats {
  id: integer
  total: integer
  total_accepted: integer
  total_rejecged: integer
}
```

I need to update the record at one go like this:

```
UPDATE stats SET total = total + 1, total_accepted = total_accepted + 1 WHERE id=1
```

So how to achieve it in Django without using a raw sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the [query expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#query-expressions):

So using the query expressions (`F()` method) your query will look like this:

```
Stats.objects.filter(id=1).update(total=F('total') + 1, total_accepted=F('total_accepted') + 1)
```